# Given gender distribution of two programmes, which one does class belong to?

Tags: statistics

Classes at a high school are divided into two branches:

- Mathematics (65% boys)
- Languages (45% boys)

Matthew observes that 55% of his class is made up of boys. Which branch does it most likely belong to: Mathematics or Languages?

I believe the answer can be found by solving Bayes' theorem for each branch, but I'm not sure how to set it up.

I'd appreciate any help given in standard P(A|BI) notation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $M$ be the mathematics branch, $M'$ be the languages branch, and $B$ signify "boys."

We are given $\mathbb{P}\left(B\mid M\right) = 0.65$ and $\mathbb{P}\left(B\mid M^{\prime}\right) = 0.65$.

Furthermore, for this particular class, $\mathbb{P}\left(B\right) = 0.55$.

By the Law of Total Probability, 
$$\mathbb{P}\left(B\right) = \mathbb{P}\left(B \cap M\right) + \mathbb{P}\left(B \cap M^{\prime}\right) = \mathbb{P}\left(B \mid M\right)\mathbb{P}\left(M\right) + \mathbb{P}\left(B \mid M^{\prime}\right)\mathbb{P}\left(M^{\prime}\right)\text{.}$$
Since $\mathbb{P}\left(M\right) = 1 - \mathbb{P}\left(M^{\prime}\right)$, you just need to put in the numbers now and see which one is higher: $\mathbb{P}\left(M\right)$ or $\mathbb{P}\left(M^{\prime}\right)$ .

Comment: Thanks for the help. I get M = M' = 50%, so the boy's class is equally likely to be in either of the branches. Or is it the sizes of the two terms that should be evaluated?

Comment: Nevermind my question. Gave it some extra thought and 50% is indeed correct. Thank you!